# Python: Multiplying numbers in a list of tuples and totalling it

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to create a code where the first two numbers of a tuple are multiplied, and then totaled with other tuples. Here's my very wonky code:

```
numbers = [(68.9, 2, 24.8),
             (12.4, 28, 21.12),
             (38.0, 15, 90.86),
             (23.1, 45, 15.3),
             (45.12, 90, 12.66)]

def function(numbers):

    first_decimal = [element[1] for element in numbers]
    integer = [element[2] for element in numbers]

    string_1 = ''.join(str(x) for x in first_decimal)
    string_2 = ''.join(str(x) for x in integer) 
    # It says 'TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number',
    # but doesn't this convert it to a string??

    tot = 1
    for element in first_decimal:
        tot = float(first_decimal) * int(integer)

    return tot

function(numbers)
```

Forgot about the output. So basically what is needed is the total of:

```
total_add =  68.9 + 2, 12.4 + 28, 23.1 + 45, 45.12 + 90
```

i.e. the first two numbers of every tuple in the list. Apologies.

Comment: What, *exactly* are you trying to do? What is the expected output?

Comment: Can you please explain What is the Question here ?

Comment: You are calling `float` and `int` on your *lists* containing floats and ints...

Comment: Could you give sample I/O please?

Comment: `tot = float(first_decimal) * int(integer)` line is wrong you cannot passes type list to `float` and `int` functions. `first_decimal` and `integer` are lists

Comment: Why are you converting your lists of numbers into strings just to convert them back in the first place? If you eventually get this right, the effect will be nothing (except to make your code slower and harder to reader), so why not just not do it?

Comment: As per your Question you asking  whether `     string_1 = ''.join(str(x) for x in first_decimal)
    string_2 = ''.join(str(x) for x in integer) ` lines convert it to a string. yes what happens there is it convert every element into string and concatinate and create one string if `first_decimal = [2,28,15,45,90]` string_1  will be `'228154590'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you literally want to add up the product of the first two elements in each tuple, then you can use the `sum()` function with a generator:

```
>>> sum(t[0] * t[1] for t in numbers)
6155.299999999999
```

which we can check is correct through the following

```
>>> 68.9 * 2 + 12.4 * 28 + 38.0 * 15 + 23.1 * 45 + 45.12 * 90
6155.299999999999
```

Answer (score 1):

My preference is to use a vectorised approach via `numpy`:

```
import numpy as np

numbers = [(68.9, 2, 24.8),
           (12.4, 28, 21.12),
           (38.0, 15, 90.86),
           (23.1, 45, 15.3),
           (45.12, 90, 12.66)]

a = np.array(numbers)

res = np.dot(a[:, 0], a[:, 1])

# 6155.3
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, `element[1]` will give you the second entry of the tuple, indexing for a tuple or list always starts at `0`. Apart from that, you're giving yourself a hard time with your function by converting variables back and forth. Not sure what you are trying to do with this part anyway:

> string_1 = ''.join(str(x) for x in first_decimal)
>   string_2 = ''.join(str(x) for x in integer)

It seems pretty unecessary. Now to give you a solution that is similar to your approach. Basically, we enumerate through every tuple of the list, multiply the first two entries and add them to the total amound:

```
numbers = [(68.9, 2, 24.8),
       (12.4, 28, 21.12),
       (38.0, 15, 90.86),
       (23.1, 45, 15.3),
       (45.12, 90, 12.66)]


def function(numbers_list):
    total_add = 0
    # Because numbers is a list of tuples, you can just
    # use `len()` to find the number of tuples
    for tuple in range(len(numbers_list)):
        total_add += numbers_list[tuple][0] * numbers_list[tuple][1]
    return total_add

function(numbers)
```

or simply:

```
def function(numbers_list):
        total_add = 0
        for tuple in numbers_list:
            total_add += tuple[0] * tuple[1]
        return total_add
```

which can be further shortened to Joe Iddons answer:
`total_add = sum(t[0] * t[1] for t in numbers)`